# unicode \begin{verbatim} with cmtt?

Tags: verbatim, unicode, typewriter

A lot of leading-edge programming languages (like Coq and Agda) allow nearly unrestricted use of unicode symbols in program text, so you can have math characters like `$\otimes$` (Unicode U+2A02) as operators in your program.

I'd like to be able to cut and paste these programs directly into my LaTeX documents inside a verbatim-like environment and get a reasonable result.  For various reasons I can't use the listings environment -- I need the typeset output to look the same as the program looks on the computer screen, even if the listings package would make it "prettier".

Unfortunately the computer modern typewriter (cmtt) font, which I really like a lot, doesn't have math symbols, but there ought to be some package that acts like verbatim using cmtt wherever possible and falls back to the math fonts when it encounters a unicode symbol that isn't in cmtt.

A package like this would probably require a major effort to "line up" the unicode math symbols with the [Latex Symbols List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), but once a table like that were to be compiled it would be really, really useful!

So, I guess my question is in two parts: has anybody compiled such a table, and (more importantly) has anybody used it to produce a verbatim that makes a "reasonable effort" at handling unicode math characters?

Comment: Is everything written unicode? or just the attachments?

Comment: Just the stuff to be verbatimized.  My latex code is plain old ascii.

Answer (score 11):

I recommend using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and loading an appropriate Unicode font for the verbatim that requires those symbols. pdfLaTeX won't cut it in this case, I'm afraid.

Comment: Unfortunately the arXiv won't accept anything other than latex or pdflatex.

Answer (score 1):

The question is now [answered.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16007/32143) If there aren't many symbols, you can use `newunicodechar` package to manually map unicode characters to LaTeX code.

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{⟨}{\ensuremath{\langle}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do like this:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}

{\scriptsize \verbatiminput{fileToInput.txt}}
```

Maybe \verbatiminput does the work for you?

/Have fun

Comment: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:⟨ not set up for use with LaTeX.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters tells us that U+0008 = Backspace. What are you trying to include?

Comment: The "8" isn't the character code; it's just part of how latex prints error messages.  The actual character is "⟨" which is 2329 "left pointing angle bracket" (look just after the colon).

Comment: But then something is really fishy, since I have include a lot of code that had { and } in them...

Comment: Johan, please look more carefully!  Those aren't curly braces.

Comment: Interesting, looks like a < but it's not... What char is '⟨'?

Comment: Left angle bracket.  You know, the math notation for ordered pair... those aren't less-than and greater-than signs.  BTW, this is just the first error in my document; there are hundreds.  I guess I picked a bad example.

Comment: Funny, I've been mistaking those for left parentheses (except that I know they aren't supposed to be that) on-screen...

Comment: '⟨' is $\langle$